# ID valus pass from ajax but not receive in Action method Why?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-treeview

I am Using kendo UI Treeview, there is ajax call of post method , in browser i see there is id=xx value pass but when i check by debug point in actionmethod i can't get  value there is null why?

i have put code am i doing something wrong?

//View page code

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
               .Name("treeview1")
               .DragAndDrop(true)
               .DataTextField("Name")
               .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               .Read(read => read
                   .Action("Categor", "CategorySet")
                ))
```

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Categor(int? ID)
{
    return Json(categories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Browser Code means ajax call

```
GET http://www.xyz.com/Admin/CategorySet/Categor?id=2 200 OK 96ms
```

See in url there is ?id=2 But in Action method i can't get this 2. Why.
?
How to solve this?

Thank you in advance 
Vinit

Comment: kindly post your ajax part, the issue may be caused by the ajax call

Comment: I don't know in kendo UI Ajax call how to do this GET To Post, here Kendo UI script automatic call get but let me try and this same code work in othere PC Why?

Comment: I am not sure but In this Extension Method `.Action("Categor","CategorySet")` try to see if you have another signature who allows you to put `FormMethod.Post` Enum in youur method

Comment: Can you suggest any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue might be with case of `ID`

change `ID` to `id`

```
public ActionResult Categor(int? id)
{
    return Json(categories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I have Do that also but no change same thing happen not get id

Answer (score 1):

You pass the wrong call:

try this:

GET **http://www.xyz.com/Admin/CategorySet/Categor?ID=2** 200 OK 96ms

instead of this:

GET **http://www.xyz.com/Admin/CategorySet/Categor?id=2** 200 OK 96ms

Comment: i have notice that and i have change it but still my paramer data is not receive... not i pass GET http://www.xyz.com/Admin/CategorySet/Categor?id=2 200 OK 96ms  and in controller i also change parameter int? id but not success

Comment: I have to use Kendo UI in This ui There is automatic function which pass id means there is a treeview on which node i select there is a call for method with selected node's id.

Comment: if you want to see how it's work then see this 2nd video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CPediqnIt8&list=PLLGlTD7u3kMrRXlKSyAkUGS3YGyc1gCo

Comment: yes i have put break point , this call is receive by method but that parameter not received it's still null

Answer (score 0):

- Please note Read action is an asynchronous call and on load i.e on first call id will be null always
- For Ex:  
   Parent1 ID 7--> Child1 ID 8
           Parent2  ID 9--> Child2 ID 6--> SubChild1 ID 5
- On First Load id's will be NULL if you press Continue(F5) on second call you will receive ID 7 to get its children .. like this this action will be called until you reach last child

Hope you got it.. because its working fine for me